# Keep cat contained in a pet play fence. What to use for cover to not escape?

Tags: cats, containment

My cat had surgery on the back foot with a split on for 6 weeks. Cat in a wired crate with an opening to a pet play fenced area without a cover. What do I use as a cover to keep the cat from climbing out?

Comment: do you mean splint? Also, how big is the play area and what is it made out of. A picture would be helpful

Comment: Are you restraining the cat because the vet said to limit his movement, or some other reason?

Comment: How big is the fenced area and what type of fence is it (i.e. can it support any weight on top)?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to cover the top of the enclosure with a thin blanket and clip it into place using something like binder clips. However, with this solution you run into the risk of the cat getting its nails caught in the blanket.

Comment: I am now using a wooden board to cover the wired pet playpen. Thank-you for your response